# Condense multiple files to a single BASH script

Tags: bash

I have a .body, .script, and .sql that I would like to condense in to a single script but I am not sure how to go about it.

.body contains the e-mail message.

.sql spools the data to a .csv:

The .script runs the .sql, and sends an e-mail with the attached `Report.zip`:

```
sqlplus $user/$pass@$db @script.sql

(cat script.body; uuencode Report.zip Report.zip) | mail -s "Report" user@domain.com -- -f no-reply@domain.com
```

Is it possible that this (including the SQL) can all be done in a single BASH script?

Comment: `... sends an e-mail with the attached Report.csv`.  Your script seems to use `Report.zip` instead, not that it makes a difference but you should be careful while posting a question.

Comment: What do you mean by 'condense'. What is your desired output/action here?

Comment: @cmh The aim is to have it all inside one script, the SQL query\spool and e-mail. I just don't understand how to go about it and could do with an example maybe.

Comment: Let those be different.  It's probably cleaner this way.

Answer (score 1):

If you can just pass the script into the stdin of sqlplus you can do:

```
sqlplus $user/$pass@$db << END
<contents of sql script here>
END

(cat script.body; uuencode Report.zip Report.zip) | mail -s "Report" user@domain.com -- -f no-reply@domain.com
```

if you still want stdin (useful if it might ask for a password or something) and assuming sqlplus won't try anything with the script file you can do:

```
sqlplus $user/$pass@$db START <(cat << END
<contents of sql script here>
END)

(cat script.body; uuencode Report.zip Report.zip) | mail -s "Report" user@domain.com -- -f no-reply@domain.com
```